# Pushing array into another array PHP

Tags: php

I have multiple arrays being created inside a loop. A single array looks like the following:

```
'Event' => array(
        'customer_id' => '107',
        'user_id' => '124',
        'date' => '23-07-2014',
        'time-options' => '0',
    )
```

I then want to push the array into another array, and the expected result has to be like following:

```
$finalData = array(
    array('Event' => array('customer_id' => '107','user_id' => '124','date' => '23-07-2014','time-options' => '0',)),
    array('Event' => array('customer_id' => '108'...)),
);
```

I have been trying the `array_push()`, but it gives me an index array which is not the expected result.

I look forward to any sort of help or guidance.

Comment: *"but it gives me an index array"* - what exactly does that mean?

Comment: array_push will produce default number index as $array[] = $something;

Comment: Post the code that gives the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$finalData = array();
```

Then just add arrays like this:

```
$finalData[] = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'customer_id' => '107',
        'user_id' => '124',
        'date' => '23-07-2014',
        'time-options' => '0',
    )
);
$finalData[] = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'customer_id' => '123',
        'user_id' => '123',
        'date' => '23-07-2014',
        'time-options' => '1',
    )
);
```

Note that $finalData is also an indexed array and that when you say you are expecting this:

```
$finalData = array(
    array('Event' => array('customer_id' => '107','user_id' => '124','date' => '23-07-2014','time-options' => '0',)),
    array('Event' => array('customer_id' => '108'...)),
);
```

it is the same as:

```
$finalData = array(
    0 => array('Event' => array('customer_id' => '107','user_id' => '124','date' => '23-07-2014','time-options' => '0',)),
    1 => array('Event' => array('customer_id' => '108'...)),
);
```